# ImageMagic work locally, not work in build

Tags: javascript, imagemagick, next.js, pm2

I use ImageMagic in my project. I did not install anything else for that.
It's work locally.

I currently have three objects created, but images are not always created, there is no such problem locally (yarn dev), only with the build. And as a consequence, of the prod.

step 1

```
item = await Item.createObject(user, template);
```

step 2

```
...
public static async createObject(...) {
...
    for(...) {
        result = await this.createInstance(user, template);
        ...
    }
}
```

step 3

```
private static async createInstance(user, template) {
    ...
    const { imgName, description } = await Image.imageMagicCreate(...);
}
```

step 4

```
import * as shell from 'shelljs';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as appRoot from 'app-root-path';

// itemId - input data;

class Image {
public async imageMagicCreate(data: IMagicData) {

const userFolder = './uploads/' + user.userName;
const baseImage = appRoot.path + '/static/template.png';
if (!fs.existsSync(userFolder)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(userFolder);
}
const itemsFolder = userFolder + '/items';
if (!fs.existsSync(itemsFolder)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(itemsFolder);
}
const thumbsFolder = userFolder + '/thumbs/items';
if (!fs.existsSync(thumbsFolder)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(thumbsFolder);
}

shell.exec(
   `convert ${baseImage} -resize 420x380 \
   -gravity south \
   -fill '#5e6e87' -font Bookman-LightItalic -pointsize 14 -annotate +0+165 '${txtPart1}' \
    -fill '#5e6e87' -font Bookman-LightItalic -pointsize 14 -annotate +0+140 '${txtPart2}' \
    -fill '#5e6e87' -font Bookman-LightItalic -pointsize 14 -annotate +0+115 '${txtPart3}' \
    ${itemsFolder}/${itemId}.png`,
    {async: true},
    () => log('item created successfully'),
);

shell.exec(
   `convert ${baseImage} -resize 420x380 \
   -gravity south \
   -fill '#5e6e87' -font Bookman-LightItalic -pointsize 14 -annotate +0+165 '${txtPart1}' \
    -fill '#5e6e87' -font Bookman-LightItalic -pointsize 14 -annotate +0+140 '${txtPart2}' \
    -fill '#5e6e87' -font Bookman-LightItalic -pointsize 14 -annotate +0+115 '${txtPart3}' \
    ${thumbsFolder}/${itemId}.png`,
    {async: true},
    () => log('thumbnail created successfully'),
);
}
}

return {
     imgName: `${itemId}.png`,
     description,
};
```

It's work locally ok, but not correct work if i did build, than start with command:

```
pm2 start ./eco.system....
```

I have to draw 6 images, 3 large 3400 * 2600 px, and 3 thumbnails 420 * 360px. All thumbnails are drawn, then not all, then one big picture is there, the second one is cropped, 3rd is an empty file, then it is not at all ... As if it doesn’t have time to draw, but it seems like the {async: true} setting is.

**logs:**

```
0|MyProject  | (node:17046) DeprecationWarning: collection.count is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. Use collection.countDocuments or collection.estimatedDocumentCount instead
PM2          | Change detected on path uploads/K0FuL5m0_/certificates/SQ-A000000219.png for app MyProject - restarting
PM2          | Change detected on path uploads/K0FuL5m0_/certificates/SQ-A000000219.png for app MyProject - restarting
PM2          | Change detected on path uploads/K0FuL5m0_/certificates/SQ-A000000219.png for app MyProject - restarting
PM2          | Stopping app:MyProject id:0
PM2          | Stopping app:MyProject id:1
PM2          | [Watch] Process name MyProject is being stopped so I won't restart it
PM2          | [Watch] Process name MyProject is being stopped so I won't restart it
PM2          | Change detected on path uploads/K0FuL5m0_/certificates/SQ-A000000219.png for app MyProject - restarting
PM2          | Change detected on path uploads/K0FuL5m0_/certificates/SQ-A000000219.png for app MyProject - restarting
PM2          | [Watch] Process name MyProject is being stopped so I won't restart it
PM2          | [Watch] Process name MyProject is being stopped so I won't restart it
PM2          | Change detected on path uploads/K0FuL5m0_/certificates/SQ-A000000219.png for app MyProject - restarting
PM2          | [Watch] Process name MyProject is being stopped so I won't restart it
PM2          | Change detected on path uploads/K0FuL5m0_/certificates/SQ-A000000219.png for app MyProject - restarting
PM2          | Change detected on path uploads/K0FuL5m0_/certificates/SQ-A000000219.png for app MyProject - restarting
PM2          | Change detected on path uploads/K0FuL5m0_/certificates/SQ-A000000219.png for app MyProject - restarting
PM2          | [Watch] Process name MyProject is being stopped so I won't restart it
PM2          | [Watch] Process name MyProject is being stopped so I won't restart it
PM2          | [Watch] Process name MyProject is being stopped so I won't restart it
PM2          | App name:MyProject id:1 disconnected
PM2          | App [MyProject:1] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2          | App name:MyProject id:0 disconnected
PM2          | App [MyProject:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2          | pid=17056 msg=process killed
PM2          | App [MyProject:1] starting in -cluster mode-
PM2          | pid=17046 msg=process killed
PM2          | App [MyProject:0] starting in -cluster mode-
PM2          | App [MyProject:1] online
PM2          | Stopping app:MyProject id:2
PM2          | App name:MyProject id:2 disconnected
PM2          | App [MyProject:2] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2          | App [MyProject:0] online
PM2          | Stopping app:MyProject id:3
PM2          | pid=17073 msg=process killed
PM2          | App [MyProject:2] starting in -cluster mode-
PM2          | App name:MyProject id:3 disconnected
PM2          | App [MyProject:3] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2          | pid=17083 msg=process killed
PM2          | App [MyProject:3] starting in -cluster mode-
PM2          | App [MyProject:2] online
PM2          | App [MyProject:3] online
```

**Thanks for any help!**

Comment: when running the "builded" version, got any message? stack? log?

Answer (score 0):

Overall, I figured out the problem. 
All the code was correct, the problem was here, the log wrote to me, but I did not understand them =(

```
PM2          | Change detected on path uploads/K0FuL5m0_/certificates/SQ-A000000219.png for app MyProject - restarting
```

In eco.system file must change option watch from true to false.
A similar problem is described [here](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1759).